# Using small letter after a period

Tags: punctuation, capitalization, periods

Is the second sentence correct?

> This is a dummy sentence. interk is the best service provider.

Here "**interk**" is the name of a service provider, which is registered with first letter small.

Comment: Companies styling their names in lowercase only became fashionable in the last few years. I'm not a fan of it as it messes up sentence case in the way you've described. But it's their name, so if that's how they write it, it's conventional to follow suit.

Comment: I agree with @Lawrence, and would add that by choosing a non-standard rendering, this new outfit is dooming itself to being misspelled, misunderstood and misconstrued for the duration of its ephemeral corporate existence.  Tagging a child with the a given name like "Featherstoneaugh" has a similarly unfortunate effect...

Comment: Note that company names should generally be italicized, or in quotes.

Comment: We have the question when we start a sentence with *iPhone*.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, and also examples like "pH" in science, it's often best to restructure the sentence. Then you can use the correct form of the awkward word, and start the sentence with a capital.

Answer (score 0):

Registered brand and product names should always remain in their original form, no matter where they are standing in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

We respect registered trademarks the same way we do with regular names. You are supposed to write "af Gyllengrip" or "bin Laden" beginning with lowercase letters. It's the same for company names.

In your case, though, you might want to rephrase your sentence to something like:

> This is a dummy sentence. I think interk is the best service provider.

or

> One of the best service providers is interk.